# How to get newer version of a package installed for 18.04?

Tags: package-management

I have another question about [`opensmtpd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mail/opensmtpd) on Ubuntu 18.04...

```bsh
apt-get install opensmtpd
```

... installs version `6.0.3p1-1build1`, which has a problem:

The systemd `opensmtpd.service` seems to think that `ExecStop=/usr/sbin/smtpctl stop` will stop the service.  However `smtpctl stop` yields a non-zero exit code and its output also hints at that it doesn't know about that subcommand:

```
possibilities are:
discover
encrypt
pause
resume
show
log
monitor
profile
remove
schedule
trace
uncorrupt
unprofile
untrace
update
```

I find that this problem has been [recognized](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893367) and [fixed](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/universe/o/opensmtpd/opensmtpd_6.0.3p1-4/changelog) in versions `6.0.3p1-2`

That was March 2018, well over a one and half year ago.

I see that newer versions do get installed for [Ubuntu 18.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/mail/opensmtpd) and [19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/mail/opensmtpd).... so how can it be that this- and newer releases since then, haven't made it into 18.04 yet?

How could this be made to happen?

Comment: Non-security updates are rarely backported to older releases of Ubuntu for several reasons (there are some exceptions). Generally, the accepted way to get newer software is to run a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: It would seem that something that is clearly a bug would warrant making an exception for, wouldn't it?
Also, I'm surprised to learn that the latest LTS version would be considered old already.

Comment: Depends entirely upon the severity of the bug and the popularity of the package. Do note that Ubuntu developers are working on their *third* release since 18.04, so it might not seem like an 'older' release to you, but others may see it differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options here:

- You have to write comprehensive bug-report to launchpad with `apport-bug opensmtpd` to inform the developers about possible problem.
- You have to install package from *disco* on *bionic*:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opensmtpd/opensmtpd_6.0.3p1-5_amd64.deb
  sudo apt-get install ./opensmtpd_6.0.3p1-5_amd64.deb
  ```

  But this manually installed package will not receive security updates.

---

**Update:** I have reported [bug 1840586](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opensmtpd/+bug/1840586) for you with backport / SRU (stable release upgrade) request.

Comment: Ad option-1) It does seem rather odd to have to bug-report for something that has already been recognised as such, -fixed, _and_ released, but if that's what it takes to get it moving...

Comment: I have reported bug for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Awesome!

Comment: While waiting for that to happen, I suppose as a third option I could investigate differences between the `6.0.3p1-1build1` and later versions, and locally craft a so-called "[drop-in snippet](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#edit%20UNIT%E2%80%A6)" to override the `opensmtpd.service` unit's `ExecStop` definition;

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile, I've investigated the differences between Bionic's and Disco's `opensmtpd` packages, and concluded that [the default `ExecStop` behaviour](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=) of `systemd` is sufficient to make `opensmtpd` indeed, stop.

`diff -p ./{bionic,disco}/lib/systemd/system/opensmtpd.service`:

> ```
> *** ./bionic/lib/systemd/system/opensmtpd.service 2018-01-16 17:18:40.000000000 +0000
> --- ./disco/lib/systemd/system/opensmtpd.service  2018-03-18 16:16:45.000000000 +0000
> *************** After=network.target
> *** 6,12 ****
>   [Service]
>   Type=forking
>   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smtpd
> ! ExecStop=/usr/sbin/smtpctl stop
>
>   [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target
> --- 6,12 ----
>   [Service]
>   Type=forking
>   ExecStart=/usr/sbin/smtpd
> ! ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
>
>   [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

Afaict, disco's `ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID` line is simply the `systemd` default behaviour made explicit.

So. here's the temporary workaround I've settled upon for now while we wait & hope for @N0rbert's [bugreport](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166467/959040) to be picked-up:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install opensmtpd
sudo systemctl edit opensmtpd.service
```

... then copy/paste this into the editor:

> ```
> [Service]
>
>     ##  While waiting for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opensmtpd/+bug/1840586)
>     ##  to be fixed, work around it as follows:
>     ##
>     ##  Clear `ExecStop` to get the [default systemd behaviour](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=)
>     ##  back;
>     ##
>     ExecStop=
>
> # vim: syntax=systemd expandtab shiftround shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=4
> ```

...and  finally, reload and restart:

```bsh
sudo systemctl restart opensmtpd
```

Proving that it works:

```bsh
journalctl -u opensmtpd
```

> ```
> ...
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 systemd[1]: Stopping OpenSMTPD SMTP server...
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 smtpd[2163]: Exiting
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenSMTPD SMTP server.
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 systemd[1]: Starting OpenSMTPD SMTP server...
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 smtpd[5987]: info: OpenSMTPD 6.0.3-portable starting
> Aug 19 10:10:13 ip-10-0-2-210 systemd[1]: Started OpenSMTPD SMTP server.
> ```

Hoping someone may find this useful.